# how to create or expand an identity-like matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to creating a matrix like this:

```
[[A 0 0], 
 [0 B 0],
 [0 0 C]]
```

in which A,B,C could be **either a submatrix or a constant**

suppose I got one of the submatrix first:

```
[[1 2], 
 [3 4]]
```

then got the next:

```
[[5 0 0], 
 [0 6 0],
 [0 0 7]]
```

How can I concat them into the format like below?

```
[[1 2 0 0 0],
 [3 4 0 0 0],
 [0 0 5 0 0], 
 [0 0 0 6 0],
 [0 0 0 0 7]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `scipy.linalg.block_diag`

As follow:

```
from scipy.linalg import block_diag
A = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
B = [[5, 0, 0], 
     [0, 6, 0],
     [0, 0, 7]]

block_diag(A, B)
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 4, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 5, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 6, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 7]])
```